# Can i have a faster performance for this loop?

Tags: java, performance, loops

I am reading a book and deleting a number of words from it. My problem is that the process takes long time, and i want to make its performance better(Less time), example :

```
Vector<String> pages = new Vector<String>();  // Contains about 1500 page, each page has about 1000 words.
Vector<String> wordsToDelete = new Vector<String>();  // Contains about 50000 words.

for( String page: pages ) {
    String pageInLowCase = page.toLowerCase();

    for( String wordToDelete: wordsToDelete ) {
        if( pageInLowCase.contains( wordToDelete ) )
            page = page.replaceAll( "(?i)\\b" + wordToDelete + "\\b" , "" );
    }

    // Do some staff with the final page that does not take much time.
}
```

This code takes around 3 minutes to execute. If i skipped the loop of **replaceAll(...)** i can save more than 2 minutes. **So is there a way to do the same loop with a faster performance ?**

Comment: What’s worse, this code has no effect. After its execution, your vectors will be unchanged.

Comment: Since you're using `(?i)`, you don't need to convert the page to lowercase.

Comment: FYI: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Comment: @Charlatan: I am using lowercase to check first if the wordToDelete exist in the page or not. Please see my comment for @Bozho.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can process page in a different way. The basic idea is following

```
for (String word : page) {
    if (!forbiddenWords.contains(word)) {
        pageResult.append(word);
    }
}
```

Here `forbiddenWords` is a set.
Also, `for (String word : page)` is a shorthand for parsing page into a list of words. Don't forget to add whitespaces to result too (I skip that for clarity).

The complexity of processing one page in original version was ~ 50000*1000, while now it's only ~1000. (checking if word is in `HashSet` takes constant time)

**edit**
Since I wanted to divert myself from work for ten minutes, here's the code :)

```
    String text = "This is a bad word, and this is very bad, terrible word.";
    Set<String> forbiddenWords = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("bad", "terrible"));

    text += "|"; // mark end of text
    boolean readingWord = false;
    StringBuilder currentWord = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int pos = 0; pos < text.length(); ++pos) {
        char c = text.charAt(pos);
        if (readingWord) {
            if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                currentWord.append(c);
            } else {
                // finished reading a word
                readingWord = false;
                if (!forbiddenWords.contains(currentWord.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    result.append(currentWord);
                }

                result.append(c);
            }
        } else {
            if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                // start reading a new word
                readingWord = true;
                currentWord.setLength(0);
                currentWord.append(c);
            } else {
                // append punctuation marks and spaces to result immediately
                result.append(c); 
            }
        }
    }

    result.setLength(result.length() - 1); // remove end of text mark
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Nice. But I guess there are whitespaces and punctuation marks that are not taken into account (or are they?)

Comment: @Bozho You're right, some technical details are omitted (like this and text parsing). Although they won't affect time complexity, they'll certainly make code bigger.

Comment: +1 anyway. I guess figuring out these details won't be that hard :) For example a page can be split so that each punctuation mark is counted as "word", and the append adds a whitespace after each word.

Comment: @Nikita: Thanks a lot for the effort. There are 2 problems here, the first 'Bozho' has mentioned where there are a lot of commas, dashes and such staff in my pages. The other problem is that the forbidden words could be 2 or more words per word, like 'bad word' in your example. That's why i looped on the forbidden words and not on the pages' words directly.

Comment: @Brad First is not problem at all and second can be fixed if you keep record of the last word before last.

Comment: @Nikita: Sorry, what do you mean by that ... "keep record of the last word before last" ?

Comment: @Brad Clumsy wording. When checking blacklist, also check "lastWord currentWord" pair. lastWord can be retrieved from `result` StringBuilder or you can have a separate variable for it. If there's a match, you can delete last word from StringBuilder just by reducing its length.

Comment: @Nikita: But it can be 3 or 4 words, not just the last word !

Comment: @Brad C'mon, you can read last 3, 4, etc words in a loop. But it's very interesting blacklist you've got :)

Comment: @Nikita: That is because the users of the application define that list themselves, and mostly their list contains sentences, not just words :(

Answer (score 5):

For a start, you can get rid of the `contains(..)` check. It adds unneeded overhead. And it will return true sometimes, when this is not the case. For example it will return `true` for "not", even if there is only "knot" on the page.

Another thing - replace `Vector` with `ArrayList`.

And as Konrad indicated in his comment - you are not changing the vectors. `String` is immutable, so you are not changing the objects. You'd have to use `set(..)` (and maintain an iteration index).

Comment: You are right about the "not"/"knot". But for the contains(...) it does not cause an overhead ... On the contrary, since 1000s of the words to delete do not actually exist in the pages, this condition saves me lots of time, as replaceAll(...) is slow. If i omitted contains(...) the process will take more than 5 minutes in my case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have a double for loop. These are generally poor performance and equate to x*y performance. Also since strings cannot be changed every single time you call toLowerCase and then replaceAll you are creating a new string. So you are creating x*y number of strings containing a whole page for each word in your list. This can be avoided using the MULTI_LINE and CASE_INSENSITIVE options in a regex.

You can reduce it to one loop and use regex to replace all the words at once.

```
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (String word : wordsToDelete) {
        if (buffer.length() != 0) {
            buffer.append("|");
        }
        buffer.append("(\\b");
        buffer.append(word);
        buffer.append("\\b)");
    }

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(buffer.toString(), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);

    List<String> newPageList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String page : pages) {   
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(page);
        String newPage = matcher.replaceAll("");
        newPageList.add(newPage);
    }
```

Comment: I would put the \\b once outside the brackets rather than repeating it for each word. e.g. \\b(word1|word2|word3)\\b  The Pattern.compile may be start enough to work out its the same. ??

Comment: It depends on what he wants to have happen. If you don't put \b on each word then the list {"hello", "world"} will replace "helloworld". If you put \b it will NOT replace "helloworld" and only work with "hello world"

Comment: I really like this solution. I have tried it, but it is still slower. I think the created buffer is so big, that when applying this large pattern on each page it takes long time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.lang.StringBuilder` - it's created specially for modified text.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(page);
for (String word: wordsToDelete) {
    int position = 0;
    int newpos = 0;
    while ((newpos = builder.indexOf(word, position))>=0) {
        builder.delete(position, position+word.length());
        position = newpos;
    }
}
```

It's just the idea - it doesn't check for word boundaries

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the pages are independent, and if you have multiple cores around, and you've got a lot of pages to process, this loop could be parallelized, also:

```
final ArrayList<String> pages = ...;
final Set<String> wordsToDelete = ...;
final ExecutorService pageFrobber = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);  //pick suitable size
final List<Callable<String>> toFrobPages = new ArrayList<Callable<String>>(pages.size());

for( final String page: pages ) {
    toFrobPages.add(new Callable<String>() {
       String call() {
         return page.toLowerCase().replaceAll( "(?i)\\b" + wordToDelete + "\\b" , "" );
       }
    });
}

final List<Future<String>> frobbedPages = pageFrobber.executeAll(toFrobPages);
// the above will block until all pages are processed
// frobbedPages will contain a set of Future<String> which can be converted to strings
// by calling get()
```